# Drawable in listview causes memory allocation too much?

Tags: android, memory-management, imageview, drawable, image-loading

I have a view pager with four pages, and each page have a listView. Everything's ok so far, but when i scroll the list it kicks thousand times GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC and it dicreases performans of my app. So i track allocations by DDMS by following [Romain Guy's documentation](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/07/track-memory-allocations-on-android/) and saw that's because of loading images to list items.

I save images and then check if there is that image as saved before, if there is, i use:

```
 img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
```

When i get allocation tracks, it shows me that this line has allocated lots of memory while scrolling... I just wonder why? And if there is any affective way to load images to suggest me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html   try this one it may be helpful to you....

Comment: Loading image from assets or from SDCard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you need to show some 'N' number of images in a list view and this images are getting from internet.

Refer: [Fedors Lazy Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: I guess Fedors LazyList example is easy enough and has affective performans. Thanks. I'll give it a shot. But i still wonder why getting from drawable causes this much memory allocation..

Answer (score 1):

The best document you can find is here : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

But it's quite complex to be honest. In next version of [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice), we hope to provide a way to encapsulate all this complexity (ui-spicelist module).

Comment: It is indeed, but i'll check it out. Thanks for your response.